# Support library version of WorkManager

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-workmanager

Is there a support library version of WorkManager. In the release notes of [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#pre-androidx-deps), there is a pre androidx version 1.0.1 available.

But on adding the same as dependency `implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1"`, the imports are still coming as `import` **androidx**.work.Worker .

Any ideas on how to add the WorkManager for a project still depending on support libraries?

Edit 1 : As per the note in the documentation link, the WorkManager 1.0.1 was a part of androidx package but still dependent on non androidx libraries. Looks like it is just a name that is getting referenced to androidx then.

Answer (score 0):

You might confuse between package and dependencies. Let take a look their note again and I will explain it later.

> Note: WorkManager classes are already in the androidx.work package, but currently depend on non-AndroidX dependencies including the Support Library 27.1 and associated Arch component versions. A version of WorkManager with AndroidX dependencies will be released in the future.

**Dependency**

They mean they not yet migrate this version to AndroidX project. So Pre-AndroidX project still can use this version as normal and not required us to migrate our project to AndroidX too.
--> *This version can use in both `Pre-AndroidX` and `AndroidX` project.*

`WorkManager` from version `2.x.x` will required us to migrate to AndroidX project.
--> *Start from this version, it can use only with `AndroidX` project.*

**Package**

Why `WorkManager` class is in package `androidx.work` while it is still `Pre-Android` dependency?
--> I think they not well prepared or move it to `androidx.work` by mistake or it is their first initialization.

So we no need to concern about package name. The advantage is we can use it with our Pre-AndroidX project.